# Is there an easy way to add a checkbox to a balloon tip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon, popup-balloons

Is there an easy way to add a checkbox (or any other custom control, for that matter) inside a balloon tip?

I want to provide the user with an optional checkbox that reads "Never show this message again".

The balloon tip in question is shown using `NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip()`.

Comment: Semantically, balloon tips are not tooltips. And the method is actually [`NotifyIcon.ShowBallonTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip.aspx). I wouldn't even mention this, but I almost posted the incorrect answer to your question before reading it more carefully. Anyway, edited now so +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an example project can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EmbCtrlNotIc.aspx